# restrictions in treeview JS - Check only one checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, treeview

I have a small problem with a "treeview" done in JS
The treeview works fine, but now I need to apply some restrictions.

The treeview has the following structure:
  Parent> node> sunode

The restriction is that I can not select more than one "node" within the "parent", and in turn, within its "node", I can not select more than one "subnode". That is, I can only mark between each parent node a checkbox.

If I set another checkbox inside the "subnode", you have to deselect the checkbox that had and mark the new one (like a radio button).

And the same with the "node", can only have marked a node within each "parent"

```
<div id="treeview-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Parent 1</li>
            <li>Parent 2
                <ul>
                    <li>node 2.1</li>
                    <li>node 2.2
                        <ul>
                            <li data-value="2.2.1">subnode 2.2.1</li>
                            <li data-value="2.2.2">subnode 2.2.2</li>
                            <li data-value="2.2.3">subnode 2.2.3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>node 2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>parent 3
                <ul>
                    <li data-value="3.1">node 3.1</li>
                    <li data-value="3.2">node 3.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here the JS:

```
    (function( $ ){
    var plugin = {
        name: 'TreeView',
        version: '1.0.0'
    }
    var defaults = {
        debug : false,
        autoExpand : false,
        css : {
            list : 'fa-ul',
            listItem : 'fa-li fa',
            collapsed : 'fa-caret-right',
            expanded : 'fa-caret-down'
        }
    }
    
    var settings;
    var debug, me = null;
    
    function __changeHandler( e ) {
        var currentTarget = $(this);
        var isChecked = currentTarget.is(':checked');
        
        debug.log(currentTarget);
        debug.log("Checked ", isChecked)
        
        if (!isChecked) {
            debug.log('Uncheck all childs');
            
            currentTarget.parent()
                         .find('input.tw-control')
                         .prop('checked', false);
        }
        
        if (isChecked) {
            debug.log('Check my parents tree');
            
            currentTarget.parents('li')
                         .find('>input.tw-control')
                         .prop('checked', true);
        }
        
        _toggleCollapse( currentTarget );
        
        me.trigger('treeview.change', currentTarget, me);
    }
    
    function _toggleCollapse ( element ) {
        debug.log("Toggle collapse");
        
        var chk = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        
        if (chk.is(':checked')) {
            debug.log('Open checked branchs');
            chk.parent()
               .find('>ul.collapse')
               .collapse('show')
               .parent()
               .find('>i.fa-li')
               .removeClass(settings.css.collapsed)
               .addClass(settings.css.expanded);
        }
        
        if (!element.is(':checked')) {
            debug.log('Hide branch');
            
            element.parent()
                   .find('ul.collapse')
                   .collapse('hide')
                   .parent()
                   .find('i.fa-li')
                   .removeClass(settings.css.expanded)
                   .addClass(settings.css.collapsed);
        }
    }
    
    function _init() {
        debug.log( "Initializing plugin" );
        
        me.on('change', 'input.tw-control', __changeHandler);
        
        debug.log("Collapsing tree");
        
        
        me.find('>ul')
          .addClass(settings.css.list)
          .find('ul')
          .addClass('collapse ' +  settings.css.list)
          .parent()
          .prepend(
              $('<i></i>').addClass(settings.css.listItem + ' ' +
                                    settings.css.collapsed)
          );
          
        if (settings.autoExpand) {
            me.find('ul.collapse').collapse('show');
        }
        
        debug.log("Adding checkbox");
            
        me.find('li').each(function( index, element ) {
            var elmt = $(element);
            
            var chk = $('<input/>').prop('type', 'checkbox')
                                   .prop('class', 'tw-control')
                                   .prop('value', elmt.attr('data-value'));
            
            debug.log("Checking if the element is selected");
            
            var isChecked = elmt.attr('data-checked');
            
            elmt.prepend(chk);
            
            if ( isChecked ) {
                debug.log('Toggle checkbox');
                
                chk.prop('checked', true);
                
                chk.trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }
    
    function _fill( data ) {
        $( data ).each(function (index, element) {
            me.find('input[value="' + element + '"]')
              .prop('checked', true)
              .trigger('change');
        });
    }
    
    var publicMethods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            me = this;
            
            settings = $.extend( defaults, options );
            
            debug = $.Logger(settings.debug, plugin);
            
            _init();
            
            debug.log('Ready');
            
            _fill ( options.data );
            
            return this;
        },
        selectedValues: function() {
            debug.log("Getting selected values");
            
            var chk = me.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
            var output = [];
            
            chk.each(function(index, item) {
                var item = $(item);
                
                if(typeof item.parent().attr('data-value') !== typeof undefined) {
                    output.push(item.attr('value'));
                }
            })
            
            return output;
        }
    }
    
    $.fn.treeview = function (options) {
        if ( publicMethods[options] ) {
            return publicMethods[ options ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof options === 'object' || ! options ) {
            // Default to "init"
            return publicMethods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  options  + ' does not exist on jQuery.treeview' );
        }
    }
    
}( jQuery ));

$('#treeview-container').treeview({
            debug : true,
            data : ['3.2', '2.2.3']
        });
```

http://codepen.io/vilacactus/pen/BpMjOp?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may listen for the ***treeview.change*** event and set checked to false for all the siblings:

```js
$('#treeview-container').treeview({
  debug : false,
  data : ['3.2', '2.2.3']
});
$('#treeview-container').on("treeview.change", function (e, ele) {
  if ($(ele).parents('ul').length > 1) {  // not on root elements
    $(ele).closest('li').siblings().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Checkable-Collapsible-jQuery-Tree-View-Plugin-Treeview/dev/logger.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Checkable-Collapsible-jQuery-Tree-View-Plugin-Treeview/dev/treeview.js"></script>


<div id="treeview-container">
    <ul>
        <li>Parent 1</li>
        <li>Parent 2
            <ul>
                <li>node 2.1</li>
                <li>node 2.2
                    <ul>
                        <li data-value="2.2.1">subnode 2.2.1</li>
                        <li data-value="2.2.2">subnode 2.2.2</li>
                        <li data-value="2.2.3">subnode 2.2.3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>node 2.3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent 3
            <ul>
                <li data-value="3.1">node 3.1</li>
                <li data-value="3.2">node 3.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```